# If $\omega(A)=\|A\|$, why $r(A)=\|A\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(F)$. The following quantities
$$\|A\|=\displaystyle\sup_{\substack{x\in F,\\ \|x\|= 1}}\|Ax\|,$$
$$r(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n},$$
and
$$\omega(A)=\sup\left\{|\langle Ax\mid x\rangle|\,;\;x\in F,\;\|x\|= 1\right\},$$
denote respectively the norm, the spectral radius and numerical radius of $A$.

> I want to prove that
>   $$r(A)=\|A\|\Longleftrightarrow \omega(A)=\|A\|.$$

It is well know that
$$r(A)\leq\omega(A)\leq\|A\|,$$
for every $A\in\mathcal{B}(F)$. So clearly if $r(A)=\|A\|$ then $\omega(A)=\|A\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In infinite dimension this is not true. If you consider the $n\times n$ "shift", i.e. $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^nE_{j,j+1}^{(n)}$, then $\omega(S_n)=\cos \pi/(n+1)$ and $\|S_n\|=1$ and $r(S_n)=0$. If we form 
$$
A=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N} S_n,
$$
then
$$
\|A\|=\sup\{\|S_n\|:\ n\}=1,
$$
$$
\sigma(A)=\overline{\bigcup_n\sigma(S_n)\}}=\{0\}
$$
so $r(A)=0$, and 
$$
\omega(A)=1
$$
since the numerical range is the closed convex hull of the union of the numerical ranges, which in this case amounts to an increasing union of concentric balls.